# Typescript Object.assign() alternative fix?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to make the following code work.

File: foo.ts

```
const Foo = () => {

    const api = {

        address: (): string => {
            return '';
        }
    };

    return api;
};

export default Foo;
```

File: bar.ts

```
import Foo from './foo';

const Bar = () => {

    let api = {

        name: (): void => {
            const add = api.address();
        }
    };

    Object.assign(api, Foo());
    or
    api = { ...api, ...Foo() };

    return api;
};

export default Bar;
```

In my tsconfig.json I have "target": "es6" set.  When I use Object.assign(), api.address() gives an error:

Property 'address' does not exist on type '{ name(): void; }'.

I've researched this and the recommendation is to use the spread operator.  I've tried

```
api = { ...api, ...Foo() };
```

which I'm not 100% sure is correct.  But I get the same error as above.

When I mouse over api in bar.ts it shows that only name exists

let api: {
    name(): void;
}

Any advice on what I'm doing incorrectly in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not where you were looking it. Nothing wrong is with Object.assign or spread in your example. The wrong element is in `address` function where you are referring to `api` which does not exists at this point. The fix is to just create it before and have it in the scope.

```
const Bar = () => {

  const api = Foo(); // creation of api instance
  const extApi = {
    name: (): void => {
      const add = api.address(); // referring to the instance, here was the error
    }
  };
  return { ...api, ...extApi }; // or Object.assign(api, extApi)
};
```

Comment: `let api = { ...Foo(), name: (): void => { const add = api.address(); } };` also works.

Comment: Thanks.  Both examples cleared it up for me and why it wasn't working.  I was thinking the same thing about the address was just not being seen by Bar.  You guys helped make it visually make sense to me.  Thank you